# Magento 2 Custom Module - Load Subscriber Email in PHTML file after newsletter subscription

Tags: magento2, event-observer, newsletter-subscriber

I am working on a custom module where we need to load the email address of a newsletter subscriber in a phtml file after they subscribe.

Our Observer file is triggered on a subscription event and collections the following data:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $subscriber = $event->getSubscriber();
    $email = $subscriber->getEmail();
    $promoCode = $subscriber->getNpDiscountCode();
    $data = [];
    $inputEmail = $email;
}
```

Now we need to load `$inputEmail` in a phtml file and we have yet to file a solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your event name?

Comment: You can keep the value in session and later get the value from session in your phtml

Comment: How do I do that?